# find value from specific column and copy those rows from multiple sheets and paste in a different sheet serially

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a specific data from a specific column and if that value(s) is found copy those rows and paste in a different sheet. I have near about 150 different files from which I will find specific value and paste in different sheet vertically and serially. please help me to do that. for example if "abc" value is found from column C 4/5 times then copy those rows and paste in sheet2 starting from cell A2.then same will happen from the next sheet. I have a code but it is not working properly.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Worksheet

Set test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = "Local7.Critical" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 14)).Copy Destination:=test.Range("A" & test.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above code? Is it not doing what you want / expect it to do? Is there an error?

Comment: There is no error but the only things the data which I copy and paste from sheet1 to sheet2 or sheet3 are overwriting meaning from the first text file all the "Local7.Critical" data rows are being copy paste to sheet2 but while I am copy and paste the data from second text file to sheet2 or sheet3 the first text files data which was in sheet2 or sheet3 are deleted and new data are being pasted. I want all the text files "Local7.Critical" data should come in sheet2 or sheet3 serially without delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not sure what the problem might be, may I already suggest the following edits:

```
Sub CopyCriticalData()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRowOnDestination As Long
Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
Dim shtSource As Worksheet

'Set the source sheet here
Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set shtDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lngLastRowOnDestination = shtDestination.Cells(shtDestination.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To shtSource.Cells(shtSource.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'Set the criteria in the next row
    If shtSource.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Local7.Critical" Then
        lngLastRowOnDestination = lngLastRowOnDestination + 1
        shtSource.Range(shtSource.Cells(i, 1), shtSource.Cells(i, 14)).Copy _
            Destination:=shtDestination.Range("A" & lngLastRowOnDestination)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ralph, Thanks for your reply. Here in this macro the datas are overwriting. I am importing all the text files from a folder to the excel worksheet one by one and find the "Local7.Critical" value and if found then copy all the rows and paste sheet3. here I am importing the first text file and after finding the "Local7.Critical" value and copying  and pasting the rows in sheet3 but for the second text file when the "Local7.Critical" data are found and copy paste to sheet3 previous data are deleted. so I want all those data should come serially. Thank you once again.

Comment: '1 5/26/2016 21:19 Local7.Warning Low  192.168.48.10'
'2 5/26/2016 21:19 Local7.Critical         High  192.168.48.10'
'3 5/26/2016 21:19 Local7.Info          Low  192.168.48.10'
These types of data contain in the text files where all those text files I import one by one in excel worksheet. if suppose in the first text file Local7.Critical data found then copy n paste all those rows in sheet2 else not. Similarly in second third fourth and rest of the text files "Local7.Critical" data found then copy and paste the rows on sheet2 after the existing data in sheet2.'

Comment: I adjusted the above solution. Let me know if this is what you've been searching for. Keep in mind that you may have to adjust the names `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. The criteria is still the same but can be also adjusted (if needed) in the row `If shtSource.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Local7.Critical" Then`.